# setUrl doesn't change anything in GWT

Tags: java, image, gwt

My ui.xml has this snippet:

```
<g:VerticalPanel ui:field="fooPanel">
    <g:Image ui:field="fooImage" />
</g:VerticalPanel>
```

There is also a button elsewhere. In this button's onClick event, I make a RPC service call in which I get a base64 encoded string and set it to the image thusly:

```
@UiHandler("fooButton")
public void onSubmit(ClickEvent clickEvent) {
    ...
    AsyncCallback<String> callback = new AsyncCallback<String> {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String foo) {
            fooImage.setUrl("data:image/png;base64," + foo);
            fooImage.setPixelSize(304, fooImage.getHeight() * 304 / fooImage.getWidth());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            Window.alert(caught.getMessage());
        }
    };
    fooServiceAsync.getFoo(bar, callback);
}
```

The service works fine. But why doesn't the image get displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I minimally changed your code and I get the image.

**Example.ui.xml**

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
        <g:Button ui:field="fooButton"></g:Button>
        <g:VerticalPanel ui:field="fooPanel">
            <g:Image ui:field="fooImage" />
        </g:VerticalPanel>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

**Example.java**

```
    final ExampleServiceAsync exampleInstance = GWT.create(ExampleService.class);

    @UiField
    Button fooButton;
    @UiField
    VerticalPanel fooPanel;
    @UiField
    Image fooImage;

    public Example() {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }

    @UiHandler("fooButton")
    public void onSubmit(ClickEvent clickEvent) {

    mainInstance.getFoo(new AsyncCallback<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String foo) {
            fooImage.setUrl("data:image/png;base64," + foo);
            fooImage.getElement().getStyle()
                    .setVisibility(Visibility.HIDDEN);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            Window.alert(caught.getMessage());
        }
      });
    }

    @UiHandler("fooImage")
    public void onLoad(LoadEvent event) {
          fooImage.setPixelSize(304,
            fooImage.getHeight() * 304 / fooImage.getWidth());
          fooImage.getElement().getStyle().setVisibility(Visibility.VISIBLE);
    }
```

While you are doing operations on image, actually its not added to DOM. You need to do that operation on that after it loaded.If you are resizing the image,user can first see the original image and then changed image. To prevent that hide the first image.

**ExampleServiceImpl.java**

```
@Override
    public String getFoo() {
        return "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP+gvaeTAAAAB3RJTUUH1ggDCwMADQ4NnwAAAFVJREFUGJWNkMEJADEIBEcbSDkXUnfSgnBVeZ8LSAjiwjyEQXSFEIcHGP9oAi+H0Bymgx9MhxbFdZE2a0s9kTZdw01ZhhYkABSwgmf1Z6r1SNyfFf4BZ+ZUExcNUQUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=";
    }
```

P.S. I removed variable `bar`, becuse I don't know how you use it. Maybe you will provide the implementation of `getFoo()` method from `YourServiceImpl.java` class.

Comment: `bar` is the input for the service!

Comment: D'oh. I did an inspect element and in that, the width is 304 and height is 0! Why's that?

Comment: You mean that you inspected your image? Can you provide your fooImage url?

Comment: It says `<img class="gwt:image" src="data:image/png;base64,<base64 string>" style="width: 304px; height: 0px;"></img>`

Comment: If I put a `Window.alert("Hi")` before `setPixelSize` and after `setUrl`, it works. Very weird.

Comment: Solved it by running a timer between those 2 commands for 500 ms.

Comment: @pratnala , I don't think that `Timer` is the best solution. Try to use `LoadEvent` and check my edited answer

Comment: Turned out to be a browser issue. See my edited answer please. And thanks for your suggestion. Helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Alright so the issue was this line:

```
fooImage.setPixelSize(304, fooImage.getHeight() * 304 / fooImage.getWidth());
```

fooImage.getHeight() was returning 0. But when I put a `Window.alert("random");` between the `setUrl` and the `setPixelSize` commands, the image showed in the dimensions I specified.

Hence, to solve this, I inserted the following piece of code between the `setUrl` and the `setPixelSize` commands.

```
Timer timer = new Timer() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
    }
};
timer.schedule(500);
```

Probably, by giving a delay of 500ms, it allowed the image to initialise its dimensions.

UPDATE: Turned out to be a browser issue. I was using Firefox on RHEL5 (which is the dev machine we use). When I used another machine with a much recent OS to connect to the GWT app, everything was working as expected. Sorry for the false alarm!

UPDATE 2: Well the problem existed on Firefox even on a recent OS (Windows 7 btw). Using `olgacosta`'s solution proved perfect!

Comment: I am very glad that you have everything resolved!)). But I had on a standard PC (`Windows 7` and `Firefox`) a problem with resizing the image too. So I would advise you to add the `LoadEvent` to your `fooImage`.

Comment: @olgacosta, you are right. Firefox couldn't handle it. Used your `LoadEvent` solution. All well now! :)

Comment: @olgacosta Well your solution works for Firefox but not for Chrome. And mine works for Chrome and not for Firefox. Weird browsers. I hard-coded both the height and width for now.

Comment: again the picture doesn't have enough time to boot. If you put a `Window.alert("")` before `setPixelSize()`, the image will appear. really weird

Comment: I found something but it is very old: https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=3788 **`Image LoadEvent` not fire when image not visible immediately.** Try to remove `setVisible()` and the example will work correctly